# Vue.js "@click.prevent" is hiding the HTML "required" attribute default validation message(Please fill out the field.)

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image: Please fill out this field.]

If I use  `"@click.prevent"`, I am not getting this message(Please fill out this field.) when user press `"Add User"` button with empty field.

But only `"@click"` is working fine. How can I get this message with "@click.prevent"?

```
  <div class="modal-body p-4">
                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Name"
                                required v-model="newUser.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                                placeholder="Email" required v-model="newUser.email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Phone"
                                required v-model="newUser.phone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg" @click="addDataIfValid('insert')">Add
                                User</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html to see how to deal with form validation.

You shouldn't add handler to button `@click` but form `@submit` event